# Getting VersionConflictEngineException in IBM Mobile First 6.3

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm receiving the following message on server log in IBM Mobile First 6.3 every time an Adapter is getting called:

**Stacktrace**

> [ERROR   ] Error sending bulk request: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   failure in bulk execution: [2]: index [worklight], type [devices], id
>   [b2deefe7-0d15-4ed4-b199-7e42440fc372], message
>   [VersionConflictEngineException[[worklight][1]
>   [devices][b2deefe7-0d15-4ed4-b199-7e42440fc372]: version conflict,
>   current [58], provided [57]]]     at
>   com.ibm.elasticsearch.servlet.DataReceiver.processData(DataReceiver.java:132)
>     at
>   com.ibm.elasticsearch.servlet.DataReceiver.processDataLegacy(DataReceiver.java:85)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source) ...

The adapter is executed correctly and the response is returned to the app.

Any idea why this error is happening?

Help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to add some more background information, like what is this adapter (SQL, HTTP, ...), what is it doing (where does the request go, what are you returning in the response), if there is anything special in the environment (additional software, firewalls, etc...) and so on...

Comment: It looks like something with Analytics. Are you doing any analytic logging in the app or adapter calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an internal error in analytics. The error itself is actually harmless, however the analytics platform should be catching it... A defect will be logged for the message. In the meantime, if you're not using analytics, you can disable it by removing the WAR files from the Liberty server.

If you are using analytics, then I would recommend clearing out the analytics data folder and restarting the IMF platform (this would remove any data you have stored in analytics). This is assuming that you are running in development mode. The analytics data folder can be in the same directory as the server.xml file for your Liberty server.

Comment: Clearing out the analytics data folder and restarting IMF doesn't solve the problem. By disabling analytics there are no more messages on the log. I'm currently not using it so good for now. Waiting for a fix for the bug. Thanks.